# Change label on activeadmin new button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have register a resource with a specific as name

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel, namespace: :my_namespace, as: 'My model' do
```

the new button has label 'New Mymodel', how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `as:` declaration, you should use normal Rails nomenclature: `as: 'FooBar'`. Don't include spaces. Then, you should see "New Foo Bar" on the button.

There's no need to use `as:` at all if you don't want to change the default model name (i.e. as in your example) - ActiveAdmin will sort out the name quite happily by itself.

If you're asking how to change the 'New' on the button then that's a whole different thing!